# substract element to row array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy array a and b

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

b = np.array([1,2,3])
array([1, 2, 3])
```

I would like to substract to each row of a the correspondent element of b (ie. to the first row of a, the first element of b, etc)
so that c is

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Is there a python command to do this?

Comment: your question is entirely answered by the top two responses in the marked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a python command to do this?

Yes, the `-` operator.

In addition you need to make `b` into a column vector so that broadcasting can do the rest for you:

```
a - b[:, np.newaxis]

# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [2, 3, 4],
#        [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

yup! You just need to make b a column vector first

```
a - b[:, np.newaxis]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape `b` into a column vector, then subtract:

```
a - b.reshape(3, 1)
```

`b` isn't altered in place, but the result of the `reshape` method call will be the column vector:

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Allowing the "shape" of the subtraction you wanted. A little more general reshape operation would be:

```
b.reshape(b.size, 1)
```

Taking however many elements `b` has, and molding them into an N x 1 vector.

Update: A quick benchmark shows [kazemakase's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42815287/240490), using `b[:, np.newaxis]` as the reshaping strategy, to be ~7% faster. For small vectors, those few extra fractions of a µs won't matter. But for large vectors or inner loops, prefer his approach. It's a less-general reshape, but more performant for this use.

Comment: Small addendum to the general reshaping: `b.reshape(-1, 1)` lets reshape set the size of one dimension automatically without explicitly querying `b.shape`.

Comment: @kazemakase Good point. Wasn't sure OP was ready to take on the `-1` wildcard, but since you bring it up, it tunes performance with no loss of generality. Thumbs up.